# Python classes in multiple files - do all methods need to be imported into class definition?

Tags: python, class, organization

I've started splitting a class among into several files/folders and have found that there are functions that are only needed to organize code and would never be called by anything higher-up in the class hierarchy (much less by the user). Is there someway I can import these into just the functions they're needed in rather than needing to import them into the class definition?

I'm getting a bit annoyed in my testing of getting the `AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'my_low_level_function'`?

Comment: This sounds kind of hacky. If a class is so large that you feel justified in splitting it up over multiple files, that suggests it's too large and doing too much. Are you sure it shouldn't be multiple smaller classes with better-defined roles?

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are talking about. You can put an import statement anywhere a statement is possible, so yes, you can do something like `import foo` in some function, and then in that function, do `foo.whatever()`, although note, that is goign to make `foo` *local* to the function. But again, I'm just guessing at what you are talking about. It would help if you created a [mcve] to illustrate what you mean exactly

Comment: note that the import statement is very slow even if the module is already imported, moving import statements from module scope to local scope could significantly reduce performance if those functions are called frequently.

Comment: so, it isn't clear what you mean exactly by "splitting a class over multiple files". It isn't clear what you mean by "method imported into a class definition" either

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was assuming they mean something like `class MyClass: from some_methods import method1`. Hacky as all hell, but it "works".